# How to parse dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

How can I parse dates coming in this example format `7 July 2021 at 1:36:23 AM Z` in pure javascript? Tried a lot of things even with moment.js but was not fruitful. I presume the `at` in the middle of the date is the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Edit :

Tried the `replace()` function as mentioned in the comments, It worked perfectly for chrome, but safari is throwing `Invalid Date` error.

Sample code:

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
    let newDate = new Date(date);
    let options = {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "long",
        day: "2-digit",
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        second: '2-digit'
    };
    return newDate.toLocaleDateString("en", options);
}
let dateString = "7 July 2021 at 1:36:23 AM Z"
console.log(convertUTCDateToLocalDate(dateString.replace('at', ''));
```

Comment: better to replace at first and then new Date("7 July 2021 1:36:23 AM Z"). It should work.

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: [You probably shouldn't be using momentjs for new projects](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Comment: Yes, the replace thing worked beautifully @Sodhi saab

Comment: If you want to use moment.js you could use `moment(input, "D MMMM YYYY [at] h:mm:ss A Z")` to parse the input.

Comment: Wanted to do it without moment.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace regex `dateString.replace(/at|Z/g, '')` for Safari, it worked for Safari and Chrome

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 1):

A simple parser, assuming the offset is always Z:

```js
// Parse timestamp in format "7 July 2021 at 1:36:23 AM Z"
function parseTS(ts) {
  ts = ts.toLowerCase();
  let months = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun',
                'jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
  let [D, M, Y, x, h, m, s, ap, os] = ts.split(/\W/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(Y, months.indexOf(M.substr(0,3)), D,
    h%12 + (ap == 'pm'? 12 : 0), m, s)); 
}

['7 July 2021 at 1:36:23 AM Z',
 '7 July 2021 at 1:36:23 PM Z'
].forEach(ts => console.log(`${ts} : ${parseTS(ts).toISOString()}`));
```

If you want to use moment.js, you should always [provide the format](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/known-formats/) using [tokens as for formatting](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) unless it's a [supported format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/). The "at" can be elided with square brackets:

```js
// 7 July 2021 at 1:36:23 AM Z
let d = moment('7 July 2021 at 1:36:23 AM Z', 'D MMMM, YYYY [at] h:mm:ss a Z');

console.log(d.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `h%12 + (ap == 'pm'? 12 : 0)` could be shortened to `h%12 + (ap == 'pm')*12` though it is more cryptic

Comment: @3limin4t0r—yes, but maintainers… and only saves 2 characters. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to request an ISO 8601 formatted date-time from wherever your string is coming from. Maybe there is an API option that allows you to pass the format. If you are using some custom input there might be an option to retrieve an ISO 8601 formatted string as well.

---

If for some reason you cannot change the string at its source you could always manually converted in into the correct format.

```js
const months = {
  january: 1,
  february: 2,
  march: 3,
  april: 4,
  may: 5,
  june: 6,
  july: 7,
  august: 8,
  september: 9,
  october: 10,
  november: 11,
  december: 12,
};
const meridiems = {
  am: 0,
  pm: 12,
};

const input = "7 July 2021 at 1:36:23 AM Z";
let [day, month, year, _at, time, meridiem, offset] = input.split(" ");
let [hour, minute, second] = time.split(":");

day = day.padStart(2, "0");

month = months[month.toLowerCase()];
month = month.toString().padStart(2, "0");

hour = hour % 12 + meridiems[meridiem.toLowerCase()];
hour = hour.toString().padStart(2, "0");

const iso8601 = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}${offset}`;

console.log(iso8601);
console.log(new Date(iso8601));
```

Comment: You can get all the parts in one go if split on `\W`. In *months*, june is misspelled "juny". In `parseInt(hour, 10) % 12` the use of *parseInt* is redunant,  `hour % 12` is sufficient. Having parsed the string, don't then build another string that must be parsed by the built–in parser, give the parts directly to the constructor: `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month-1, day, hour, minute, second))`, which also avoids a lot of needless formatting. ;-)